# fill text input when checking jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

i have a loop in my laravel project which contain checkbox and input

```
@foreach($s as $sh)
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="service_id[]" class="checkser" value="{{$sh->id}}"></td>
<td class="checkservice">{{$sh->name}}</td>
<td> <input type="text" class="form-control checkser inputservice" placeholder="{{trans('home.quantity')}}" name="ser_quantity[]" ></td>
<td>{{$sh->price}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

i need to fill text input with (1) when checkbox checked 
and empty this when checkbox unchecked

i tried many method but failed to work this with next input only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `jquery` and bind a `change` event handler to your `checkbox`.

Also, use `closest` method.See reference [here](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
$('.checkser').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $(this).closest('tr').find('.inputservice').val(1);
    }
    else
       $(this).closest('tr').find('.inputservice').val('');        
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help<br>
i used this before but it fill all <br> how to check the next one only
'$('.checkservice').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $(this).next('.inputservice').val(1);
       
    }
    else
       $$(this).next('.inputservice').val('');        
});`

Comment: sorry check my edit , it's working well with mono field but it's not working with loop i tried .next but not working

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try jQuery [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method

```
if($(".checkser").is(':checked'))
    $(".inputservice").val(1);  // checked
else
    $(".inputservice").val('');  // unchecked
```

Just use `$(selector).is(':checked')`

It returns a **boolean** value.

Comment: thanks for your help , i tried the first comment method and worked well